# after correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command mvn <goals>

Tags: maven

I am new in maven 
when I build ,I got this message

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Ambari Main ........................................ SUCCESS [  2.187 s]
[INFO] Apache Ambari Project POM .......................... SUCCESS [  0.038 s]
[INFO] Ambari Web ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.526 s]
[INFO] Ambari Views ....................................... SUCCESS [  0.248 s]
[INFO] Ambari Admin View .................................. SUCCESS [04:34 min]
[INFO] ambari-metrics ..................................... SUCCESS [ 26.287 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Common .............................. SUCCESS [  8.582 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Hadoop Sink ......................... SUCCESS [01:07 min]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Flume Sink .......................... SUCCESS [ 47.242 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Kafka Sink .......................... SUCCESS [ 35.241 s]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Storm Sink .......................... SUCCESS [02:29 min]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Collector ........................... FAILURE [02:44 min]
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Monitor ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Metrics Assembly ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Server ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Agent ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Client ...................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Python Client ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Groovy Client ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Shell ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Python Shell ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Ambari Groovy Shell ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12:57 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-08-24T09:36:27+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 41M/320M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project ambari-metrics-timelineservice: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-timelineservice:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.apache.ambari:ambari-metrics-common:jar:2.0.0-SNAPSHOT in apache-hadoop (http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/groups/public/) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :ambari-metrics-timelineservice
```

I have question with this: `[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :ambari-metrics-timelineservice`

what is the `<goals>` means???

I type `mvn <goals> -rf :ambari-metrics-timelineservice` in command
it said no directory named goals
Please guide me

Comment: Have you shown us the _full_ stack trace or just the bottom portion of it?  I think you should try to resolve the error rather than focusing on resuming the build.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to substitute `<goals>` with the actual goals you have called. E.g., if you executed the maven build with `mvn clean install`, then `clean install` are the goals, which means, the complete command would be `mvn clean install -rf :ambari-metrics-timelineservice`.